# contex:componet-scan not picking up beans defined in jar file

Tags: spring, jar, annotations

I am working on a Spring Project:Common that uses a combination of Annotaions and Spring IOC in XML.
I have a common.jar which contains Common classes used by various projects.

And I have another Spring Project:WebService that refers to the beans defined in common.jar.

For some reason beans marked with @Component Annotation in Common.jar are not being picked up by my WebService Project. But all beans defined using  <bean id="" class="" /> in Common.jar were picked up.

Below are the code for all files that have necessary configuration. Would really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

In Common.jar, applicationContext.xml

```
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd">

    <import resource="springConfig/app/AppServices.xml"/> <!-- Beans in this file were loaded. -->

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ipd.app1"/> <!-- Beans for all classes under app1 package were NOT loaded  -->

</beans>
```

In Common.jar, AppServices.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="inquireOrderApp" class="com.ipd.app.inquireOrderDetail.InquireOrderDetailAppImpl"/>

</beans>
```

Common.jar, com.test.app.MyClass

```
package com.ipd.app1;
    @Component("createOrderApp")
    public class CreateOrderAppImpl implements CreateOrderApp {
        @Override   
        public CreateOrderResponse processMSSOrder(TransactionContext tx,
                CreateOrderRequest createOrderRequest)
                throws ApplicationException, Exception {

            System.out.println("In App Layer Class CreateOrderAppImpl to ProcessOrder.");
            return response;
        }
    }
```

WebService Project, IpdService_IPDSoapHTTPPortImpl.java

```
 @WebService(portName = "IpdSoapHTTPPort", serviceName = "IpdService", targetNamespace = "http://ipd.com/ipdIpdweb/", wsdlLocation = "/wsdls/Ipd.wsdl", endpointInterface = "com.ipd.ipdIpdweb.IpdPortType")
@BindingType("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/http")
public class IpdService_IpdSoapHTTPPortImpl implements IpdPortType {

    ApplicationContext ctx;

    public IpdService_IpdSoapHTTPPortImpl() {
        this.ctx = AppContext.getCtx();
    }

    @Override
    public void createOrder(WSHeader wsHeader,
            CreateOrderRequest createOrderRequest,
            Holder<WSResponseHeader> wsResponseHeader,
            Holder<CreateOrderResponse> createOrderResponse)
            throws WSException {


            CreateOrderApp createOrderApp = (CreateOrderApp) ctx.getBean("createOrderApp");         
            res = createOrderApp.processOrder(tx, createOrderRequest);

            res.setResponseCode(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
            res.setResponseMessage("Success");

           .....
    }

}
```

Please let me know if you need see the code for any other file.

Comment: which version of spring are you using?

Comment: I am using Spring 3.1

Comment: @user1614808: I have the exact same problem today. Explicitly defined beans in the webap spring.xml are picked up correctly while any annotated beans in the dependency jar are not. Have you found a solution to this??

Answer (score 0):

Well add this to `applicationContext.xml`

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>
```

Comment: Aren't these for Spring MVC? Common.jar has common classes that are used by several projects its not Spring MVC project